Adding file to an empty git commit with git repo-filter not working
I'm trying to add a file to an empty git commit using git repo-filter by following the git-repo-filter insert-beginning example as referenced in an answer to How to [use] git filter-repo to add [a] file to every commit?.  But it doesn't seem to work for me.  Here what I'm doing:

Create a new empty Git repository

mkdir repo
cd repo
git init

which gives
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example$ mkdir repo
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example$ cd repo
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gdlxn/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo/.git/


Create and commit a new file.txt

touch file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "Add file.txt"

which gives
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ touch file.txt
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git add file.txt
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git commit -m "Add file.txt"
[master (root-commit) 9a8bcbe] Add file.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file.txt


Create an empty commit

git commit --allow-empty -m "Empty commit"

which gives
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Empty commit"
[master a976821] Empty commit


Use git filter-repo --commit-callback to add file.txt to the empty commit

git log --pretty="'%h' '%cd' '%s'" --date=raw --name-status                        # get the empty commit raw committer date
git ls-files --stage file.txt                                                      # get file.txt mode, id, stage, and name
git filter-repo --preserve-commit-encoding --force --replace-refs update-no-add --commit-callback '
 if (commit.committer_date == b"<empty commit raw committer date>"):                # replace <empty commit raw committer date>
   fileChange = FileChange(b"M", b"file.txt", b"<file.txt id>", b"<file.txt mode>") # replace <file.txt id> and <file.txt mode>
   print(f"{fileChange.type} {fileChange.filename} {fileChange.blob_id} {fileChange.mode}")
   commit.file_changes.append(fileChange)
   print("Added file change")
'

which gives
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git log --pretty="'%h' '%cd' '%s'" --date=raw --name-status
'a976821' '1715019143 -0400' 'Empty commit'
'9a8bcbe' '1715018968 -0400' 'Add file.txt'

A       file.txt
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git ls-files --stage file.txt
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   file.txt
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git filter-repo --preserve-commit-encoding --force --replace-refs update-no-add --commit-callback '
> if (commit.committer_date == b"1715019143 -0400"):
>   fileChange = FileChange(b"M", b"file.txt", b"e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391", b"100644")
>   print(f"{fileChange.type} {fileChange.filename} {fileChange.blob_id} {fileChange.mode}")
>   commit.file_changes.append(fileChange)
>   print("Added file change")
> '
b'M' b'file.txt' b'e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391' b'100644'
Added file change
Parsed 2 commits
New history written in 0.03 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
HEAD is now at a976821 Empty commit
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Completely finished after 0.09 seconds.


Check if file added to commit

git log --pretty="'%h' '%cd' '%s'" --date=raw --name-status

which gives
gdlxn@geoff-test4:~/addFilesToGitCommit/example/repo$ git log --pretty="'%h' '%cd' '%s'" --date=raw --name-status
'a976821' '1715019143 -0400' 'Empty commit'
'9a8bcbe' '1715018968 -0400' 'Add file.txt'

A       file.txt

As one can see from the output of step 5, file.txt is not added to the empty commit. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using git-filter-repo ae71fad1d03f with git version 2.25.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

I wonder if this behavior is because file.txt did not change between commit 9a8bcbe and commit a976821.  Is there anyway to have git show file.txt as modified in commit a976821even though it didn't change between commit 9a8bcbe and commit a976821?
